# VPN from IPv4 only to IPv6 only

Tags: networking, vpn, ipv6

I want to access my home network on the go, but it can only be reached via IPv6 from outside. The network(s) I want to reach it from usually only have IPv4. (How) Can I access the whole home network with a server in between?

Let's assume the following:

Network A (Home):

- Internal IP range: 192.168.0.0/24 (I'd like to keep IPv4 internally for now)
- Machine A: aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd (IPv6 reachable from outside)
- Machine A (internal): 192.168.0.1

Network B (Remote):

- Internal IP range: 192.168.178.0/24
- Machine B (internal): 192.168.178.2
- Public IP: 1.2.3.4 (router)

Server:

- IPv4: 2.3.4.5
- IPv6: bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee

Now I want to access 192.168.0.3 (network A) from 192.168.178.2 (network B). Can this be accomplished using OpenVPN / (SSH) tunnels / iptables / routing? If so: **How?**

Sorry, usually I have a half-working approach or at least an idea how to solve my problems, but I've been thinking about this all day and there's only chaos left in my head; so I better start from scratch. (Of course my idea is that the Server to connects the IPv6 network A with the IPv4 network B. But how?)

Bonus points if all traffic between network A & the server, and the server & network B (read: the internet) is encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention which operating systems you are using, so I can only give you generic advice:

You'll have to set up two tunnels:

- An IPv4-over-IPv6 tunnel between machine A and the server
- An IPv4-over-IPv4 tunnel between machine B and the server

On the home network you'll have to route traffic for `192.168.178.0/24` to machine A. If machine A is the default gateway then this will already be the case. Otherwise you'll have to add a static route on the default gateway to send that traffic to machine A. On machine A you'll have to configure a static route for `192.168.178.0/24` towards the IPv4-over-IPv6 tunnel to the server.

On the remote network you'll have to route traffic for `192.168.0.0/24` to machine B. If machine B is the default gateway then this will already be the case. Otherwise you'll have to add a static route on the default gateway to send that traffic to machine B. On machine B you'll have to configure a static route for `192.168.0.0/24` towards the IPv4-over-IPv4 tunnel to the server.

The server will need two static routes:

- `192.168.0.0/24` towards the IPv4-over-IPv6 tunnel to machine A
- `192.168.178.0/24` towards the IPv4-over-IPv4 tunnel to machine B

Now machines on the home network will send their packets for `192.168.178.0/24` to the default gateway. If this is not machine A then the default gateway will forward them to machine A. Machine A will forward them over the IPv4-over-IPv6 tunnel to the server. The server will forward them over the IPv4-over-IPv4 tunnel to machine B, who will forward the packets to the remote network.

Now machines on the remote network will send their packets for `192.168.0.0/24` to the default gateway. If this is not machine B then the default gateway will forward them to machine B. Machine B will forward them over the IPv4-over-IPv4 tunnel to the server. The server will forward them over the IPv4-over-IPv6 tunnel to machine A, who will forward the packets to the home network.

I explicitly wrote down each hop of the path in both directions. Communication will only work if ***every*** step described above works.

You can use many protocols and applications for setting up the tunnels. Plain IPvX-in-IPvY tunnels are the easiest, but provide no encryption. The same goes for GRE tunnels. OpenVPN is a bit more difficult to set up but does provide encryption. Take a look at the [Linux IPv6 How-To](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux%2BIPv6-HOWTO/index.html) and the [Tunnel section of the Linux Advanced Routing How-To](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.tunnel.html) to see how to set up tunnels.

Comment: Thanks! All machines are linux boxes. Assuming the Server and Machine A are running OpenVPN servers (Server to Mobile: 10.0.0.1, Machine A to Server:10.10.0.1), I woud add 192.168.178.0/24 via 10.0.0.1 and 192.168.0.0/24 via 10.10.0.1 on the Server, 192.168.178.0/24 via 10.10.0.1 on Machine A, 192.168.0.0/24 via 10.0.0.1 on Mobile (plus routes on the gateways)? Can or shoud the tunnel IPs be in the same Subnet? The route on the gateway in network B would be optional, if not all of network B needed to reach network A? Huge thanks, I'll try to set this up ASAP.

Comment: Tunnel are separate interfaces so they need their own subnet. If not every device on network B needs to access network A you could put a static route towards machine B on each device that does need it. Having a static route on the gateway is much much easier though.